# i want someone to check my code and Identified the syntax error

Tags: sql, database, oracle, subquery, union

The question is:

For each maker who has models at least in one of the tables PC, Laptop, or Printer, determine the maximum price for his products.

Output: maker; if there are NULL values among the prices for the products of a given maker, display NULL for this maker, otherwise, the maximum price.

the database is :
Short database description "Computer firm"

The database scheme consists of four tables:

```
Product(maker, model, type)
PC(code, model, speed, ram, hd, cd, price)  
Laptop(code, model, speed, ram, hd, screen, price)  
Printer(code, model, color, type, price)
```

The Product table contains data on the maker, model number, and type of product ('PC', 'Laptop', or 'Printer'). It is assumed that model numbers in the Product table are unique for all makers and product types. Each personal computer in the PC table is unambiguously identified by a unique code, and is additionally characterized by its model (foreign key referring to the Product table), processor speed (in MHz) – speed field, RAM capacity (in Mb) - ram, hard disk drive capacity (in Gb) – hd, CD-ROM speed (e.g, '4x') - cd, and its price. The Laptop table is similar to the PC table, except that instead of the CD-ROM speed, it contains the screen size (in inches) – screen. For each printer model in the Printer table, its output type (‘y’ for color and ‘n’ for monochrome) – color field, printing technology ('Laser', 'Jet', or 'Matrix') – type, and price are specified.

Code:

```
select maker,max( price ) 
from 
    ( 
        select maker, max( l.price) 
        from product p left join laptop l on p.model = l.model 
        group by maker 
        union all select maker, max( pr.price) 
        from product p left join printer pr on p.model = pr.model 
        group by maker 
        union all select maker, max( pc.price) 
        from product p left join pc on p.model = pc.model 
        group by maker 
    ) as h 
group by maker ;
```

and it gives me this error :

> Error in the query. Code: `(933) ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.`

I don't know where is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query looks like:

```
SELECT ...
FROM (
    SELECT ... FROM ...
) AS h
```

The problem is that Oracle does not allow the `AS` keyword to alias derived table. You would need to remove that keyword.

[Example on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c8967ac744a74941ca0437f9c90fcf55):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
) as X

ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

---

Another issue with your query is that you are using aggregation in the `UNION`ed subqueries but you are not aliasing the columns on which you use an aggregation function:

```
select 
    maker,
    max( l.price) -- no column alias
from product p ...
```

Then in the subquery you do:

```
select maker,max( h.price )
```

This will raise error `ORA-00904: "PRICE": invalid identifier`, since `price` does not exists in the outer query. You need to alias the column in the inner queries.

```
select 
    maker,
    max( l.price) price
from product p ...
```

---

Final version of your query:

```
select maker,max( price ) 
from 
    ( 
        select maker, max( l.price) price 
        from product p left join laptop l on p.model = l.model 
        group by maker 
        union all select maker, max( pr.price) 
        from product p left join printer pr on p.model = pr.model 
        group by maker 
        union all select maker, max( pc.price) 
        from product p left join pc on p.model = pc.model 
        group by maker 
    ) h 
group by maker ;
```

Comment: Error in query. Code: (904) ORA-00904: "PRICE": invalid identifier

Comment: this is what gives me when i remove the alias

Comment: @afbigdad: yes, that's the other problem with your code. It is explained in my answer also.

Comment: Your query produced correct result set on main database, but it failed test on second, checking database
* Wrong number of records (more by 6)